# innerHTML elements in wrong place

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

My understanding of innerHTML isn't completely clear so I'm having some trouble.

This produces all of my td's outside of the table.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var list = document.getElementById("procTable");
list.innerHTML = "<table style='border:gray solid 1px;'><tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel.length; i++) {
    list.innerHTML += "<td style='border:gray solid 1px' width='" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Width) + "'>" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Caption);
}
```

Comment: Using IE8 but same results in Chrome as well

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "outside of the table"? Maybe post a snippet of the html this code produces?

Comment: Tip: what you have inside list **before** you modify it?

Comment: Where are the end tags? Creating a table by pasting some HTML is not a good idea anyway, use DOM-manipulation instead.

Comment: Tried showing html here but keeps rendering it instead of just showing it.  Tried pre tags and the usual 4 spaces to no avail.

Comment: all my td tags are being written "after the table is written and closed again.

Comment: innerHTML is a setter. When you set the value of innerHTML it gets parsed into DOM nodes **immediately**. It's not just a string you can append to. When you assign it a table with no closing tag, it closes it for you because it's "fixing" your invalid html for you. If you want to build up a string, build it up in a local variable first, before assigning it to .innerHTML

Comment: I swear, I closed all my tags, but it closes them "again" which is confusing me. That's why I left them out with this version.

Comment: It sounds like you have a test page set up - can you upload and share a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're appending invalid HTML, the browser is helping you by adding the elements you missed out.  Then, when you add your table cells, they get appended after the closed table.

Try adding the table, then the row, then the cells.  Also, build the whole string first then append it in one go, updating the DOM (ie. using `innerHTML`) is a slow operation.

```
var list = document.getElementById("procTable");
var listInner = "<table style='border:gray solid 1px;'><tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel.length; i++) {
   listInner += "<td style='border:gray solid 1px' width='" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Width) + "'>" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Caption) + "</td>";
}
listInner += "</tr></table>";
list.innerHTML = listInner;
```

Comment: Thanks. What is invalid however?

Comment: @JohnKinane The markup `<table style='border:gray solid 1px;'><tr>` by itself is invalid.  It needs at least one child `<td>` and it needs closing tags for both elements.  The browser will create all the stuff for you, but then when you `+=` that won't be inside the table.

Comment: I understand that but when I wrote versions that closed the tags it added them in addition to what I wrote

Comment: @JohnKinane  Comment out everything except the first two lines of your code, then look at what markup is generated in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happen if you don't close your tags correctly. in your example:

```
var list = document.getElementById("procTable");
list.innerHTML = "<table style='border:gray solid 1px;'><tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel.length; i++) {
    list.innerHTML += "<td style='border:gray solid 1px' width='" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Width) + "'>" + (result.d.ProcessDataColumnModel[i].Caption)+ "</td>";
}
list.innerHTML += "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: I tried this but innerHTML added the duplicate tags after them which is really weird.